# php and ssl on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: https, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, php7

When running `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);` I get a 500 internal server error and it fails completely.

When running `$fp = fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);` I get an exception:

> Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP?

When I run `php -i | grep -i openssl` I get

```
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

As if ssl is enabled and configured correctly.
in php.ini the extension=...ssl is commented out with `;` so I'm confused. How can I proceed from here to make it work?

Thanks

Added phpinfo output of SSL
[image]

Comment: It's possible that you enabled openssl for php-cli and not for your webserver/fpm. Could you check the output of `phpinfo()` for openssl support?

Comment: See updated post, thanks